# If I was fat, and now I'm not, which is better: 我长胖 or 我长胖了 or 我长了胖 or 我长了胖了?

Tags: word-choice, past-tense

Suppose in the past I was fat, and now I'm no longer fat.  I'm wondering which 了 is appropriate:

- 我长胖
- 我长胖了
- 我长了胖
- 我长了胖了

I don't think we can just leave off the 了.  It makes sense to put 了 at the end as a [change-of-state 了](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Change_of_state_with_%22le%22).  However, it also seems to make sense to use a [completion 了](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_completion_with_%22le%22) after the verb (which I believe is 长).  Yet the [double 了](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Advanced_%22le%22_after_an_object#Usage_of_Double_.E4.BA.86) doesn't seem to apply here.

Baidu results indicate both 我长了胖 and 我长了胖了 are plain wrong (but suggests 我长了肥胖 is possible).  I don't understand why.

**Question**: If I was fat, and now I'm not, which is better: 我长胖 or 我长胖了 or 我长了胖 or 我长了胖了?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

我长胖了=I am putting on weight.

The other 3 versions are incorrect.

You should reverse it to express your purpose:

我（已经）不胖了。

我曾经很胖（但现在瘦下来了）。

Answer (score 5):

Neither.

If you used to be *x* and you're not any more you'd just use a construct like:

> 以前很*x*

like:

> (我)以前很胖

---

Of course, 很 doesn't necessarily mean *really* or *very*, but if you want to change it to 有点 that's cool too:

> (我)以前有点(儿)胖

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose in the past I was fat, and now I'm no longer fat.

You should say 我瘦下来了, 我变瘦了 or 我瘦了 in this case.

我胖了, 我变胖了 or 我长胖了 means *I'm getting fat*.

These are incorrect:

> 我长胖
>
> 我长了胖
>
> 我长了胖了

Answer (score 2):

Suppose?? All theoretical of course.

我以前很胖，现在不胖了！真的哦！